# Kohana 3.3 - Class Model not found

Tags: php, model, subdomain, kohana, kohana-3.3

The problem isn't really generic as my title says...

I've worked on Kohana site on local, and just put it online on ovh server.
This site is under a subdomain.
My connexion to mysql seems to be ok.

It can't find my models ! But I can display my views !
And it worked perfectly on my local.

I don't know which way I have to take to find my solution...

[EDIT]

I use the function Kohana::find_file() to try to find the path of my model > nothing.
But it works for my views.

Comment: Did you check if the problem was case sensitivity concerning the directory-/filenames? What error(s) do you get?

Comment: Hey, I found the problem before reading your comment. It was a case sensitive issue :o
Because on my local, I was on windows, and my host is on Linux.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem a few weeks ago and went crazy :D Glad you could solve it

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to throw me out of the window....

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you figured this out already, but what solved this problem for me was making all classes references exactly equal to the filename of the file that contains the referred class. So this reference to the class Controller_Home (Home.php in folder Controller) made from the class Controller_MyFrontend (Myfrontend.php na pasta Controller):

```
class Controller_Home extends Controller_MinhaFrontend {
```

Would be change to:

```
class Controller_Home extends Controller_Minhafrontend {
```

....or else change the filename from Myfrontend.php to MyFrontend.php